# Global configuration loaded from database for admin dashboard

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on project with back-end dashboard. I'd like to store admin settings in database, and be able to load them (preferably) on runtime in twig template. What would be the best approach to pass data to twig template? I want to avoid situation of accessing data from db in each method in `AdminController`. Is there a way to load data automatically or even better load them directly to twig template?

Comment: Take a look at the SyliusSettingsBundle

Comment: @Paziツ I went trough documentation, and it seems as its just what I need. Will give it a tray and get back to you. The only thing I could not find in docs is whether settings are being loaded on runtime or not.

Comment: Settings are saved in DB and loaded in runtime, when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Event Listener which will listen to `kernel.controller` event and make all the work for you. It will be fired right before action method.

Check the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on your app.
You could use an `EventListener`, for example on the `kernel.request` event, to retrieve & load the settings into a temporary class for each request to your backend. But if you have backend & frontend on the same app you'd need to parse the URL at each request or load the admin settings for everyone. In this case for best performance I would do it in the controller and if I need more than just retrieving the data either create a service to load the settings or use a lifecycle callback like `PostLoad`.

Comment: I use FOSUserBundle, so I dont think I would need to parse URL as my route is only accessible if `ROLE_ADMIN`.

Comment: Whatever EventListener you use you'll have to differentiate the backend and frontend if you do not want to load the settings for everybody so - depending on the event you end up using - either parse the URL / inject the router & check the route or (as of 2.6) inject the security token directly and check roles.